# scrolltop() is not work smoothly in chrome & safari but work in firefox

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser, scroll

If you check this link http://jsfiddle.net/Hbkdt/.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
       $(".fixed").css("top", $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    });
```

Move your scroller downward. Then you can saw the **.fixed** DIV work smoothly in FF but it's not work smoothly in Safari & Webkit.

I don't know how can i fix it. Any help is appreciated :)

I am using Chrome Version 22.0.1229.94 in mac.

Comment: In Chrome (latest version on mac) it is smooth. But why are you trying to position that element with JS? There is an extra css (position: fixed) property for that.

Comment: i know that but my requirement is different

Comment: Why do you need the javascript for this? What are you trying to achieve? Just keeping it smooth in the top left?

Comment: @zomboble Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Hbkdt/11/ . I am using **position:fixed;** on it. The problem it that when the window width less then 1000px then the right side is not visible. That's why i am using the JS with **position:absolute;**. TO achieve the effect

Comment: The problem why the right box isn't visible in your second fiddle is because fixed elements will be cut off at the viewport edges.

Comment: @insertusernamehere i know problem it's happens with **position:fixed;**. So you have any solution please share it.

Comment: [looks much better](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Hbkdt/14/) with just `-webkit-transition: top 0.2s`

Comment: Did you consider this approach? http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Hbkdt/26/

Comment: This is awesome please give this as an answer. So, i will accept it & can use explain it little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only using `position: absolute` and setting `scrollTop` on the element because when `position: fixed` is used, if the window width is less than the width of the element, a portion of the element is then hidden, even if you scroll right to try to see it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hbkdt/11/

A different way to approach this problem is to stick with `position: fixed`, and then to remedy the problem of a portion of the element being hidden:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Hbkdt/26/

The `left` property of the element is on scroll set in a way that makes it appear that horizontal scrolling works as desired:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".fixed").css("left", -$(window).scrollLeft() + "px"); 
});
```

Since `position: fixed` is now being used again, the vertical scrolling is perfectly smooth.

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting an *alternative*. The most favorable option to give to the smooth effect is to animate the change in position, to fake the easing.

Something like this

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".fixed").stop(false, true).animate({ "top" : $(window).scrollTop()}, 1000); 
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/LKYjm/)

This works great but when you starting scrolling with the scroll pane it starts stammering again.

But, to overcome this, you can use of [debouncing techniques](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/).

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $.doTimeout( 'scroll', 250, function(){
                         // ^ This time prevents the following code to run, 
                         //   if another scrolling occurs within this time

                         //   Thus enabling us to give a smooth scroll effect
                         //   Once the user is done scroll

        $(".fixed").stop(false, true) //break the queue fast
                   .animate({ "top" : $(window).scrollTop()}, 200);
    });
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/LKYjm/1/)

Comment: I didn't want any animation on it.

Comment: @sandeep, But its a good alternative to achieve what you are trying.

Answer (score 1):

Add a relative div inside fixed one and adjust its width on resize.

```
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="container">
         <ul>
            <li>Resize frame</li>
            <li>Test1</li>
            <li>Test1</li>
            <li>Test1</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="victim">Why i am not visible</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

​

js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var fitWidth = function() {
        $(".fixed .container").width(Math.min(
            $(window).width(), $(".fixed").width()
        ));
    };

    $(window).resize(fitWidth);
    fitWidth();
});​
```

css:

```
.fixed {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:1000px;
    background:red;
}

.container {
    background: #ff0;
    position: relative;
}

...
```

​
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hbkdt/25/)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, to pin your div at a fix location of your page, you need to use the CSS position `fixed` instead of `absolute`

Your scroll event can be removed and your CSS should be like this :

```
.fixed {
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}​
```

Here is the updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Hbkdt/17/

Comment: Please see my above comment to zomboble why i prefer js for this instead of CSS **position:fixed** . Check this jsfiddle.net/Hbkdt/11

Comment: OP has already tried this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hbkdt/11/). Read the comments too

Comment: Damned :o) So it is not a final answer, but a clue would be to avoid complete JQuery element "definition" each scroll event by defining variables : http://jsfiddle.net/Hbkdt/18/